# Dynamic module import won't compile on initial run of server

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular7

#### The problem

When running my server initially I get the error: `ERROR in Cannot read property 'members' of null`.

I've tracked this back to the following block of code:

```
const MODULES = [

    // This gets all of the page modules from the pages array of page objects
    // Then uses the spread operator to inject the resulting array of modules individually
    ...getPageModules(), <---- THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE

    // Proceed as usual
    CommonModule,
    Sidebar,
    Windows,
    Taskbar
]
```

#### The setup

So this part of a larger window system that dynamically loads components into windows.  Since the page needs a reference to the modules to import them and then window module needs a reference to the components for `entryComponents`, a window service was established in order to retrieve these to allow them to be dynamically injected into the modules.

Here is a reference to the `getPageModules` function and its related function:

`getPageModules`:

```
// Returns all of the modules for all of the pages
export function getPageModules( _pages: any[] = pages ): any[] {

    // Get all of the module elements recursively from the pages array
    return getPageElements( pages, "module");
};
```

`getPageElements`:

```
// Recursively retrieves all instances of a specific element in all page objects
export function getPageElements( _pages: any[] = pages, element ): any[] {

    // Recursively build an array of all elements.
    let elements = _pages.map( page => {

        // Return the page element, or the spread array of elements returned by a recursive call to this function
        return page[element] ? page[element] : [].concat.apply([], [...getPageElements(page.pages, element)]);
    })

    // Return the resulting elements
    return elements;
}
```

#### What I've tried

I've looked at the returns of these functions and there are no issues.  In fact this works if I comment out the problem line, save and compile (the program compiles but doesn't work because the modules are not loaded), and then un-comment the problem line and save (this program compiles and works this time since the modules are loaded.

Other than that I am at a complete loss at to why this won't compile on the initial run.

#### What I need

I'm looking for a way to dynamically load these modules and have the application compile correctly on the first run.

Comment: what does this spaghetti `getPageModules` return in the end? What happens if you just put the return of this function to the modules array?

Comment: `_pages.flatMap(page => page[element] ? [page[element]] : getPageElements(page.pages, element));`

Comment: @smnbbrv It's not really very nice to call someone's code spaghetti code. In answer to your question it returns an array of all modules associated with a given set of pages to be loaded dynamically.

Comment: @AluanHaddad This is correct, or I can use `[].concat.apply(getPageModules()` instead of `...getPageModules()`.  It was the spread operator causing the problems. Feel free to add the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'll add an an answer later. Regarding spaghetti code, I'm not really concerned with being nice, but your code is not spaghetti ;)